# Semantics of the angle between velocity vector and the positive $x$-axis

Tags: multivariable-calculus, intuition, plane-geometry, angle, plane-curves

Let's say a particle moves in plane with curvature equal to $\kappa(t) = 2t$, with constant speed of $\|v(t)\| = 5$, such that $v(0) = 5\textbf{i}$, and the particle never goes to the left of the $y$-axis. The angle that the velocity vector makes with the positive $x$-axis at time $t$ is $\alpha(t)=\frac{\pi}{2} - 5t^2$.

$\alpha(t)=\frac{\pi}{2} - 5t^2 \implies \frac{d\alpha}{dt} = -10t$, which is always negative because $t \ge 0$. That would normally imply that the angle is decreasing without bound, but intuitively I don't see how it can go below $-\pi$, so I'm not sure how to interpret that angle.

Note: This is the exercise $14.15.11$ in Tom Apostol's Calculus vol. $1$.

Clarification: We know the curvature is $\kappa(t) = |\frac{d \alpha}{ds}|$, where $s$ is arc length. To compute $\alpha$, I would like to know the sign of the $\frac{d \alpha}{ds}$. If we take $\alpha$ is always decreasing, we know $\kappa(t) = -\frac{d \alpha}{ds}$, and I can integrate to find $\alpha$. However, if the angle is constrained to be in the range $[-\pi, \pi]$, then I'm not sure how to assign the sign to the absolute value (and even the derivative is not continuous).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You almost said it yourself: "if the angle is constrained to be in the range...".

Therefore, by contrapositive (or contradiction), it must be that the angle is *not* constrained to any bounded range.

This is acceptable because an angle like $-5\pi$ is coterminal/equivalent to $\pi$. And it's actually extremely helpful for calculus so that an angle can decrease past $-\pi$ or increase past $\pi$ in a continuous or differentiable way, without having to suddenly jump by $2\pi$.

Comment: Thanks Mark! So intuitively I should just see it going in circles, so we get both periodicity and continuity. In a sense, when speed angle is decreasing without bound, it means that the thing is just going in circles clockwise.

Comment: @S11n Yes, all of that is correct. In this case since the change in/derivative of the angle is not a constant, it happens to be going in circles faster and faster, as opposed to uniform circular motion.